# mysql node js quest -- SELECT EXISTS query

Tags: mysql, node.js, select, exists

what is wrong with this logic?

```
var selectString = 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user="'+username+'")';

var queryUserExists = connection.query(selectString);
var resultsLength = queryUserExists._results.length;

console.log(queryUserExists);

if(resultsLength > 0){
   socket.write("fail user already exists"+"\r\n");

} else {
    console.log('insert=');
    var query = connection.query (
        'INSERT INTO users '+
        'SET user = ?, password = ?, token = ?',
        [username, password, token]
    );

    socket.write("success"+"\r\n");
}
```

resultsLength is always returned zero. 
What is the proper way to use this query?

returned object:

```
sql: 'SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user = \'a new user is my name\' ORDER BY user LIMIT 1',
typeCast: true,
nestTables: false,
_resultSet: null,
_results: [],
_fields: [],
_index: 0,
_loadError: null }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper code: thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/722783/mahmoud-gamal for the database query that is optimized!

```
connection.query("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user = '"+username+"' ORDER BY user LIMIT 1", function (error, results, fields) {
if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    socket.write("fail internal error"+"\r\n");
}
if (results.length  > 0) {
    console.log('fail');
    socket.write("fail user already exists"+"\r\n");

} else {


        console.log('insert');
        var query = connection.query (
            'INSERT INTO users '+
            'SET user = ?, password = ?, token = ?',
            [username, password, token]
        );

        socket.write("success"+"\r\n");


}

console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 1
FROM users
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM users 
              WHERE user = 'username')
ORDER BY user
LIMIT 1;
```

**Or:** Why not:

```
SELECT 1
FROM users
WHERE user = 'username'
ORDER BY user
LIMIT 1;
```

**Note that:**

```
ORDER BY user
LIMIT 1;
```

Are just for performance.

Comment: how would i use this in node though?

Comment: @user1392515 - Sorry replace the query in `var selectString = 'the query I posted';`

Comment: nono, of course I just did that. but my query worked before, yeilding the same response. I do not know how to parse the response to figure out if the entry is there or not.

Comment: @user1392515 With the new query, you will expect only one return value `1` in case that user is found, or `NULL` value, or the query didn't find any rows in case that user wasn't found. I don't know really how to test for this using node.js code you have, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: ah, thats great to know. here is what my object looks like though https://gist.github.com/4500696 (the relevant portions) it says result set is null and results is an empty array. The db contains a duplicate entry but its not picking it up

Comment: @user1392515 if the `_resultSet == null` then there is no user with the value `\'a new user is my name\'` do you have a user with the value `user = \'a new user is my name\'`? Try to test the query directly to MySQL, and ensure that the parameter is passed correctly to the query.

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = 'a new user is my name' ORDER BY user LIMIT 1    works in phpmyadmin sql query prompt but not in node.. still returns an empty array

Comment: @user1392515 - I noticed that, in [the link]() you pointed out to before, that the `user` variable is surronded by  \ like `\'a new user is my name\'`. This is might be the probelem. Try to print the query before you execute it, the value of user parameter shouldn't be surronded by these \.

Comment: I think it escapes quotation marks when it logs to the output for some reason. Anyway I got the working code by following some examples. Huge thanks for the query that is optimized!